# Having problem in fetching data from api using nuxtjs with async fetch() method

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am having problem while fetching data from api in nuxtjs while using async fetch() method. Error is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$get'). I tried many times but still it is showing the problem.

**index.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Blog posts</h1>
    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching posts...</p>
    <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">Error while fetching posts: {{ $fetchState.error.message }}</p>
    <ul v-else>
      <li v-for="post of posts" :key="post.id">
        <n-link :to="`/posts/${post.id}`">{{ post.title }}</n-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <nuxt-link to="about">about</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: "About the app",
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "Description",
          name: "Description",
          content: "hello",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  async fetch() {
    posts = await this.$http.$get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    console.log(posts);
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
};
</script>
```

Comment: which version of nuxt are you using ? do you have `$http` set up ?

Comment: what do see when you log `this.$http`? if it's undefined, check your configurations

Comment: Do you see `modules: ['@nuxt/http']` in `nuxt.config.js`?